# INNER JOIN wrong SUM and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which connect themselves by `name` and `dateOfInput`.

**Table documents**

```
id
name
price
dateOfDocument
dateOfInput
```

**Table customers**

```
id
identification
name
dateOfInput
```

The data I want to show in a grid is something like this:

```
Name   |  Identification  |  Total Price  | Total Quantity
John          #1               15.31            2
Stack         #13              9.90             1
```

And in the database the lines of the respective tables is:

**Rows documents:**

```
VALUES('John', 10.31, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-01 15:00')
VALUES('John', 5.00, '2015-01-02', '2015-01-02 13:00')
VALUES('Stack', 9.90, '2015-01-01, '2015-01-01 12:00')
```

**Rows customers:**

```
VALUES('#1', 'John', '2015-01-01 15:00')
VALUES('#1', 'John', '2015-01-02 13:00')
VALUES('#13', 'Stack', '2015-01-01 12:00')
```

In order to accomplish the grid I want, here's my select:

```
SELECT doc.name, cust.identification, 
       SUM(doc.price) AS `totalPrice`, 
       COUNT(doc.name) AS `totalQuantity`
FROM documents AS doc
INNER JOIN customers AS cust ON cust.name = doc.name
WHERE doc.dateOfDocument >= '2015-01-01' AND
      doc.dateOfInput = cust.dateOfInput
GROUP BY doc.name
```

The output I'm receiving is wrong in the price and in the quantity.

```
Name   |  Identification  |  Total Price  | Total Quantity
John          #1               10.31            1
Stack         #13              9.90             1
```

Comment: I got the desired results without changing anything.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fc9c/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `cust.identification` to the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

This gives me the correct result (note GROUP BY change):

```
SELECT doc.name, cust.identification,
    SUM(doc.price) AS 'totalPrice',
    COUNT(doc.name) AS 'totalQuantity'
FROM mg_tblDocuments AS doc
INNER JOIN mg_tblCustomers AS cust ON cust.name = doc.name
WHERE doc.dateOfDocument >= '2015-01-01' AND
      doc.dateOfInput = cust.dateOfInput
GROUP BY doc.name, cust.identification -- add me
```

EDIT: beaten to it :)